# Check a condition and bring a value from all the sheets of a file

Tags: excel

I´ve a file with about 50 tabs, and each with a variable name.
Each tab includes a standard form (15 columns, 1000 or more rows).
I need to check each row: 
If column D has a non-null value and column B is greater than some other value, I need to bring  the value of column A in a different tab.

I´ve to admit I thought this would be simple but I can´t find a way to make it work.
Any advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: nope, not simple. Have you thought about any approaches yet? outline these. Do you want to use a macro? my thoughts are that you'd use advanced filter + macros/automation to do this, but this would make it difficult to maintain if you are not familiar with writing macros.

Comment: Yep, that's rather straightforward. Have you attempted **anything** concrete yet? Show us some reasonable code and we will be glad to help iron it out.

Comment: I'm not clear what's going in column A. Is it pulled from different sheets in each case, or always the same sheet? At any rate, it sounds like `VLOOKUP` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the detail you've provided, my understanding is that in every worksheet you want to bring forward some value from a base tab. Thus, the following formula would work:

```
=IF(D2>0,IF(B2>100,Sheet2!A2,"2nd False"),"1st False")
```

As you copy this down across rows, it will fetch the corresponding value on the same row in another sheet, which as far as I can see is what you're after. If it isn't, then yes you would need to bring in a vlookup.

In terms of automation, either highlight all your tabs or record a macro with the following steps:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L288")
    Range("E2:E288").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.Run "'Your File.xlsx'!Macro2"
End Sub
```

Hope that is what you're after and good luck